# I replaced a surge arrestor for our home -- did I miss anything?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, surge-suppression

We're selling our home, and one of the things on our inspection was a "popped" surge arrestor - I don't have much experience at all with electrical work, but the process seemed pretty straightforward, so I saw no point in paying $280 for someone to come out and do what I could handle for $50.

Since I do have relatively little experience with electrical work though, even as easy as this appeared to be I still thought it'd be best to ask if someone could take a peak and see if there's anything immediately noticeable that I've missed?

---

[image: full]

---

[image: close up]

*edit*: I should note that when the power is turned back on, the light is glowing green.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see it looks like a direct buss connection these usually require a circuit breaker because when they fail it is a direct short to ground. It looks like you have unused double pole breakers that the device could be wired to that would be be better but usually they are rated 20-30 amps but not at the same as the main feeding the panel.

Comment: Hey, thanks - the old one was wired up like this so I assumed I'd just do the same thing. I don't see unused breakers; which ones?

Comment: There are two unused breaker positions at the bottom of the box.  Notice the "fingers coming up from the black and red bus bars and the corresponding notches on the left.  You would have to obtain and fit a breaker there.  I think Ed has in mind a 30a and since you are protected both phases, a single handle double  breaker.